# How to get month name for a given year and week in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have 2 form fields in HTML namely Year and Week.

Once the user selects a Year and a week from the dropdowns, I want to display the month Name for the selected year and week.

Can anyone help me to get month name based on year and iso week numbers.

For example: If I selected year as 2022 and week no as 16, then the expected output is `April` as a month name.

This shoud be a function that returns the month name for a given year and week.

Below is my sampke code.

```
getMonthName() {
    const year  =  2022;
    const week  = 16;
    console.log(month);
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at the material of the course you're doing. They should've given you enough info to complete the task

Comment: When does the week start in the year? i.e. what is week no.1 ?

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks. ISO week no. Is good.

Comment: Proposed a code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will display the month name (short form) for the given ISO week number and year.

```js
function getMonthName(week, year) {
let d =new Date(year,0,1+(week-1)*7);
d.getUTCDay()<5?d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()-d.getUTCDay()+1):d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+8-d.getUTCDay());
return (""+d).split(" ")[1];
}

console.log(getMonthName(1,2022));
console.log(getMonthName(11,2022));
console.log(getMonthName(16,2022));
```

Comment: It is throwing error on split` `;  It is throwing error after split inside quotes. No overload matches this call.

Comment: You may not have latest browser support. I will update it now

Comment: I update it to work normal for your browser

Comment: If it answers your question then accept it and up vote it before it gets closed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-wood-nynj7f?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

1. Create mapper for your months:
2. 4 weeks = 1 month, then get input value of week covert to number and divide 4. (Example: 16 / 4 === 4)
3. The result is a key of your mapper: months[divided result]

The best is a using Date libraries such as: dayjs, date-fns, moment, luxon or other.

```
const months = {
    1: "January",
    2: "February"
}

changeWeekHandler(e) {
   const week = parseInt(e.target.value)
   const month = Math.ceil(week / 4) // for round number to the upper (example: Math.ceil(0.25) -> 1)
   this[your input field] = months[month]
}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer to keep the explanation as well as the code.

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting form. I came up with a solution like this;

I do not suggest you divide by 4 weeks per month because not all months have 4 weeks.
But from your input, you always can know the day of year from a number of weeks

numberOfWeek * 7 = numberOfDay

create a method :

```
const dateFromDay = (year, day = 1) => {
  const date = new Date(year, 0);
  return new Date(date.setDate(day));
}

// call the method with your inputs

const myDate = edateFromDay(2022,16*7); 
// here you will have the full date 

// if you want just the month then 
myDate.getMonth();
```

For exact your need :

```
//Declare months 
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
// Declare method for receiving your month name
const dateFromWeek = (year, week = 1) => {
  
  const date = new Date(year, 0);
  return monthNames[new Date(date.setDate(week*7)).getMonth()];
}
//When you use 
dateFromWekk(2020,3); //just write year and week, you will get the name of month
```

Comment: The input is a week, not a day.

Comment: Yes. But one week always has 7 days.

Comment: So you in that method you just write numberOfWeek * 7 = number of day

Comment: So if I have `week = 12`, what day is that? How does the OP use your answer to get what they want?

Comment: _"numberOfWeek * 7 = number of day"_ is not accurate enough

Comment: 12*7 = 84; then you call method dateFromDay(2022,84); you get the full date, you want month then .getMonth

Comment: How the exact day is not accurate enough? You can not get more accurate date if you know just the number of week and number of year.